# Run cross-site javascript for a specific iframe in browser console for loaded page

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, iframe

Is it possible to run javascript commands on a browser for one iframe of the current loaded document (via console or javascript: in URL)?

Since it's a different domain, if i try `document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow.document;` i get an access denied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're using firebug:

```
cd(frames[0]);
// run stuff now
```

I don't think it's currently possible in webkit debuggers (it wasn't as of about 6 months ago, but that may have changed), wouldn't have a clue how to do it in IE.

Comment: found a way to do it in chrome, just run "chrome.exe --disable-web-security" and it let you select stuff inside the iframes :)

Comment: @bortao - nice, didn't know _that_ :)

Comment: @cwolves I was trying this out - looks like there are some issues with it. I can `cd` to the frame but variables still show up as undefined. Found [this](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=814) and [this](http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000520.html)

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - I'm using FB 1.6X.1b2 and variables seem to resolve fine, FYI.

Comment: Ah, I'm on FF4.01 + FB1.7.1b1 - the fix probably hasn't made it's way to the 1.7.x branch yet!